# UiBinder Placeholder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

how can I create a placeholder with in the UiBInder, to later fill it with e.g. a Tree element? (Like the Flextable, but simpler).

Regards, Stefan

Answer (score 7):

```
<g:SimplePanel ui:field="panelForTree" />
```

Then, in Java:

```
@UiField protected SimplePanel panelForTree;

...

panelForTree.setWidget(theTreeYouMadeLater);
```

Comment: A small caveat in this approach is that you end up with an extra DIV in the markup. The SimplePanel is acting more as a container rather than a placeholder.

Comment: I agree with Carlos, small caveat but important.  How could one do it without a extra div (or other html element)?

Comment: You have to insert your Tree in something, right?  If you're not inserting it in something then you should make it the base widget of your UiBinder, and instantiate it when you need it.